# NodeJS + Node-MongoDB-native: sort objects in alphabet order

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting

I'm trying to sort objects in collection by "name" parameter in alphabetical order. Here's the code I'm using:

```
app.get('/companies', loadUser, function(req,res){
    db.collection("companies",function(err,collection){
            collection.find({}, { sort:[['name',-1]]},function(err, companies) {
                var companies_list = new Array();
                companies.each(function(err, company){
            ... 
            });
    })
});
```

I actually don't understand how exactly sort parameter works and what is -1. The [official documentation](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/docs/queries.md) didn't help me. Thanks!

Comment: Does this code work, if not what Error messages do you get? In the docs I can't see that they're using the mongodb sort definition of 1 (ascending) and -1 (descending) rather than asc and desc.

Comment: You wiil suprise, but right NOW this code works as expected. It even sorts my records in alphabet order. It's really very strange. I spent over 3 hours yesterday with the same code, and can't get it work.

Comment: maybe you had some small typo in it or something else. And what I forgot with the previous comment was that Strings will be sorted alphabetical, not sure how it behaves if you have mixed types, but I guess they will be converted to Strings as well.

Comment: Well, it seems so. At least, records beginning from "_" jump on the top of the list, same thing with numbers. Also, maybe you know, does Mongoose have any advantages over mongo-native-driver? I'm just noticed a lot of people use Mongoose instead of this...

Comment: no I have no experience with mongoose, so I can't tell what makes it "special"

Comment: Mongoose is an ODM with plenty of syntactic sugar. If you are only performing a few queries, its probably not worth it to use Mongoose. But as your application grows, Mongoose keeps you organized and writing less code. Development time, IMO, is worth more than processing time (although, Mongoose is quite efficient and processing time is negligible at best)

Comment: `[..] collection.find(  {}, {  sort:{'name':-1} }, function([..]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I'd rather use

```
{ sort: [['name': 'desc']] }
```

because it's more explicit. Both methods work though.

When omitting the sort-direction:

```
{ sort: 'name'}
```

it sorts ascending.